# How to enable “Abbreviations” on code blocks on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: plugins, code-blocks

[Abbreviation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSgsS.png)
I'm new user on Ubuntu. I use Ubuntu 14.04. Here, while I install code blocks I found that "Abbreviations" is not enabled here. Now how can I enable this on my code blocks 13.12?

Comment: Give us a better screenshot.

Comment: please see the [link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/10-ways-to-customize-codeblocks.html)
Here you find more about "Abbreviation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By installing "codeblocks-contrib" package on code blocks can solve this problem.
We can do this by terminal:

> apt-get install codeblocks-contrib